# xmla4js I keep getting Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin ajax header

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmla

I am using XMLA4JS library.

The url of the xmla service is on another domain.  I keep getting error message:
**Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin ajax header**

I have not modified any of their code and I am using their samples.

I entered url of the OLAP cube that is deployed on another server.
I passed userid and password in the url as the query string but no luck...

Please suggest how I should be able to connect to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard issue when doing ajax cross domain requests. The xmla4js wiki has a page that explains it, and offers a solution too: http://code.google.com/p/xmla4js/wiki/SettingUpAnApacheProxy

Another approach which might work is to enable CORS headers at the server side. See http://enable-cors.org/